# Visual studio 2010 locking issue when developing user controls

Tags: file, visual-studio-2010, locking

I researched quite a lot on this but finally seemed to pin down on this issue. Visual Studio some times randomly locks the build dll/exe file if you have custom controls in your project.
Steps to replicate:

1. Create a winforms app/dll project
2. Add a new class, say CustomButton that inherits from Button
3. Build
4. Create a form. Look in the toolbox, and the custombutton appears allowing you drag it on your form
5. [This now becomes random] the next build of your project will either proceed or fail requiring you to restart visual studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: UPD: Deleting controls/tab from Toolbox does not help

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have found a [temporary] solution. It seems M$ "fixed" this in later versions, but it still does not work. Anyways, here is solution: remove automatic version incrementing in the assembly version attribute. This seems to resolve the issue however it's somewhat inconvenient.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533411

> Temporary workaround would be disable
>   assembly version update after the
>   rebuild. In AssemblyInfo.cs file,
>   remove the wild card from the
>   AssemblyVersion attribute, for
>   example: replace this: [assembly:
>   AssemblyVersion("1.4.*")] [assembly:
>   AssemblyFileVersion("1.4")] with this:
>   [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.0.0")]
>   [assembly:
>   AssemblyFileVersion("1.4.0.0")]

**UPD Again :(** 
The above did not solve the problem. I am still going to leave it in case somebody else encounters something like this, but the question remains open.